# Expand div to full page size with content already in place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a clickable circle on the top left corner that expands to full page when clicked on. I got it to work using a scale

```
.hover.opened {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g571o6ou/

Now I would like the red circle's content to be already in place (ie not scaled because it looks bad) but not visible and the red circle expands to reveal it's content. (illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HQd3.png as you see the content is not scaled up, it is already at the correct scale but only visible where the red circle has grown)

How would you do that? Is that even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this http://jsfiddle.net/2hamed/jrqto8cv/ ?

Comment: @Hamed That's exactly what I wanted, if you post this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted, thanks

Comment: Sure, done and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a somewhat different approach than yours.

Html:

```
<div class="top-circle">
    <div class="inner-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    background:#555;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.top-circle{
    top:0;
    left:0
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius: 0 0 5000px 0;
    transition:all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.inner-text{
    margin: 50px;
    width:500px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('.top-circle').click(function(){
        $(this).width($(window).width()+500);
        $(this).height($(window).height()+500);
    });
});
```

And this is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hamed/jrqto8cv/).

Answer (score 1):

With a little CSS3 you could approach it in a different way. Think of it as creating a mask that reveals a fixed content underneath.

So the red color is not applied to the parent div that in your case draws the circle, but on the background of the nested div.

Here is an example based on your code using *clip-path*:

```
.youtube {
    -webkit-transition: scale(1);
    transition: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at left top);
    clip-path: circle(50px at left top);
    height: 100%;
}
.youtube.opened {
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100% at center);
    clip-path: circle(100% at center);
}
.hover-content {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/1cgonza/trn8oy8o/

It is not the most cross-browser solution at this point in time, but it might get you started. It tends to work better if you use SVG images as clip-path. Read through this and some of the links at the end for more ideas: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, I'll definetly try to use SVG next time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g571o6ou/1/)

```
.hover.opened {
transform: scale(1);
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
overflow: hidden;
font-size:50px;
transform: scale(0.50);
```

}

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g571o6ou/3/)

Comment: Not really, like I said I don't want the content to be scaled with the top left circle, I want it to be already in place but only visible on the parts where the circle has scaled. I want it to be "revealed" by the animation of the circle.

Comment: Now you can check with the updated fiddle. Let me know if its working with you.

Comment: I'm sorry if I explained myself badly. The gray background will contain a whole bunch of things, the red circle is just a modal. While your solution is exactly what my illustration should be, it doesn't really fit my needs. Thanks a lot for your time tho

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting ?

```js
var youtubePanel = document.querySelector(".youtube");

youtubePanel.addEventListener("click", function() {
 youtubePanel.classList.add("opened");
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color: #BBB;
}

body {
 background-color: #3D4045;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hover {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hover.hover-top-left {
 top: -1000px;
 left: -1000px;
 width: 2000px;
 height: 2000px;
}

.hover-content {
 position: relative;
    top: 66%;
    left: 69%;
    transform: scale(20);
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 65px;
    width: 900px;
}

.youtube {
 background-color: #CC181E;
 border-radius: 100%;
 transform: scale(0.05);
}

.hover.opened {
 transform: scale(0.25);
 transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hover.opened>.hover-content {
 transform:scale(1);
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover hover-top-left youtube">
    <div class="hover-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, as I said in another comment I don't want the content to be scaled with the circle. I've edited my message to explain the illustration a bit more.

Comment: I have edited the sample now m which the content is not wrapping.